# How to call a Restfull web service that have basic authentication using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: rest

I am using Tomcat7, Sprng framework for restfull web services. I am trying to call an http web service that have basic authentication using Spring RestTemplate.

I couldn't get it to work. Can anybody please tell me based on the code below what do I need to change to make it able to call the http restfull web service that have basic authentication.. Also can anybody tell me or provide me with the pom.xml file which java libraries would I need?

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.journaldev.spring.controller.EmpRestURIConstants;
import com.journaldev.spring.model.CostControlPost;
import com.journaldev.spring.model.Employee;
import com.journaldev.spring.model.RfxForUpdate;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;


public class TestExample2 {

    public static final String SERVER_LIST="http://abc/sourcing/testServices";


    @Test
    public void testGetListOfServiceNames()
    {
        try
        {               
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(SERVER_LIST,HttpMethod.GET,null,String.class);
            assertNotNull(response);    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("e:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }                   
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**In simplest form:**

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =  new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password);
    httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
    ClientHttpRequestFactory rf = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    template = new RestTemplate(rf);
```

**Spring Automatic Management:**

Create HTTP context for RestTemplate:

```
 private HttpContext createHttpContext() {
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();

        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(host, basicAuth);

        BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localcontext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
        return localcontext;
    }
```

Add the interceptors:

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(
  new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
```

Call:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
  "http://abc/sourcing/testServices", 
  HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

Refer [this](http://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring) post.